# Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <NA> in EMP_ID Column. Expected type is Double

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

I am reading one excel file having two sheets. Both the sheets having same column but different values. In first sheet, column name is emp_Id having NA as a value so when I am reading first sheet in first iteration it is running absolutely fine and all the values are stored in table of my database, but in 2nd iteration when i am reading second sheet it is also having NA as a value in emp_ID column, but is giving exception 
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in EMP_ID Column.  Expected type is Double.

```
    string sourcePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTP_Path"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RxdataExcelFile"];
            string ExcelConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourcePath + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConStr))
            {
                try
                {
                    //OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    var i = 1;
                    while (i <= 4)
                    {                    
                        ds.Clear();
                        //OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
                        var query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet" + i + "$]";
                        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
                        connection.Close();
                        oda.Fill(ds);
                        var xml = ds.GetXml();
                        Rxdataxml = xml.ToString();
                        i = i + 1;


                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                }
            }
```

Comment: You might need to read each cell as a `string` and then clean and parse in memory into the data structure you need.

Comment: have a logic to convert `NA` to double (maybe 0 or null if your db column is nullable)

Comment: My guess is the type of the column in the second sheet is different from the first one.

Comment: Does `NA` becomes first value on second sheet's `EMP_ID`? I ever experienced misreading of data type when reading from `DataSet` with id data type set as double but first value in Excel sheet contains letters, hence add some logic to filter `NA` before using `OleDbDataAdapter`.